# What are these text-box-like formatting entries in my word template?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, symbols

I'm looking to get an understanding of what these text box like formatted items are in my microsoft word template / document.

I have googled extensively to try to find the answer, I was able to find a list of template format symbols and their definitions but whatever this is, is not listed.

Also I checked extensively into word text boxes and what they're for and how they're used and it didnt seem to be one of these either, although it looks VERY similar to a text-box, perhaps a text-box with a title or comment description?

Anyways, they are kinda stubborn and arent being flexible so i'd like to figure out what they are so i can better understand how to use/edit them, or if i need to just get rid of them altogether.

Many thanks,
lifo

[image: word text box 1]

[image: word text box 2]

Microsoft Word Home 2013 on a W10 20H2 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called quick parts.

> You can use the Quick Part Gallery to create, store, and reuse pieces of content, including AutoText, document properties (such as title and author), and fields. These reusable blocks of content are also called building blocks. AutoText is a common type of building block that stores text and graphics. You can use the Building Blocks Organizer to find or edit a building block.
>
> To open the Quick Part Gallery, on the Insert tab, in the Text group, click Quick Parts.

To change the content from a quick part:

> You can change a Quick Part by replacing the building block. You insert the building block, make the changes that you want, and then save the building block with the same name.

To delete a quick part:

> 1. Open a document that contains the Quick Part that you want to delete.
> 2. On the Insert tab, in the Text group, click Quick Parts, and then click Building Blocks Organizer. If you know the name of the building block, click Name to sort by name.
> 3. Select the entry, and then click Delete.
> 4. When asked whether you are sure you want to delete the building block entry, click Yes.
>
> The building block that you deleted is no longer available in galleries, although the content might still appear in the document.

**Source:** [Use Quick Parts and AutoText in Word and Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-quick-parts-and-autotext-in-word-and-outlook-7a527697-058f-4967-b8f1-aae0774e4813):

Comment: wow thanks a million, i NEVER ran across ANY of this while exhaustively searching/reading about word template formatting

Answer (score 0):

### They are called Content Controls, specifically, these are Document Property Content Controls.

Here is my page on these: [Repeating Data Using Document Property Content Controls or other Mapped Content Controls](https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart).

The Document Property Content Controls can be found under Document Properties on the Quick Parts menu. They are not the only document properties but are special, as explained on my page. These are also known as the "Cover Page Document Properties." These are built-in Mapped Content Controls.

Mapped Content Controls are very good for repeating data. I think they are the premier way of doing so in Word 2007 and later. The Mac version of Word does not have a way in the user interface to manipulate them, but they do work in the Mac version. You can create and modify them using vba, though. [Content Controls for the Mac OS](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/) by John Korchok.

More General Content Controls can be more versatile, though. There are a number of kinds; those under that menu are primarily plain text controls. Others can be found under the [Developer Tab](https://addbalance.com/word/developertab.htm#PageStart). You can edit manipulate the Document Property Content Controls using that tab. This is also explained on my page.

Here are links to a couple of Greg Maxey's pages on Content Controls:

- [Word Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html)
- [Mapped Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html)
- [Create a Form Using Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_fillin_form.html)